# PHPunit to test catch block

Tags: php, testing, phpunit, try-catch

I have a code like this one:

```
public function one()
{
   try {
      $this->two();
   } catch (Exception $E) {
      $this->three();
   }
}
```

How can i test that `$this->three()` function is called?

I've tried to "mock by code" `$this->two()` and throw error instead of it's original code, but that ends up with error caught by phpunit itself.

Tried setExpectedException, but it also doesn't solve the problem - catch runs inside phpunit again and just ignored.

Function `$this->three()` never called in both cases.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "mock by code"?

Comment: It seems that your class placed inside namespace. Try `\Exception`

Comment: @amrhady, i use runkit_function_redefine to change code and i'm changing it to `throw new \Exception('test');`

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that the described method were in a class which was placed in a namespace containing it's own Exception implementation. So I was catching an `\Namespace\Exception` while throwing an `\Exception`.

Throwing correct exception did the thing.

@sectus, thank you!